# adb push changes file permissions

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am trying to push the file on my windows machine with read only permissions.
-rw-------.
But when i push the file with adb push to the device, the file permissions changes to -rw-rw-rw-.

While browsing the adb code, I found the following lines (I have not debug and check if these get executed but just found it incode):

```
/* copy user permission bits to "group" and "other" permissions */
370        mode |= ((mode >> 3) & 0070);
371        mode |= ((mode >> 3) & 0007);
```

Can anyone help to understand the reason?

I also found following link from Google users:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/YE8NdH9xE3c

But could not make out of it much.

Comment: You could change them after the file is pushed

Comment: It may be for [files that get pushed or synced don't end up with different permissions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/YE8NdH9xE3c)